# Can I create an expandable Listbox for a Listitem in ZK?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, zk

Can I add a `Listbox` as child to a `Listitem` when the Listitem is selected? I'm currently working with hybris and the code I've tried is this :

```
    Listitem listitem = new Listitem();
    listitem.setValue(123);
    listitem.setParent(this.secondListBox);
    this.secondListBox.addItemToSelection(listitem);
```

And

```
 private EventListener<Event> getListBoxListener() {
    return (event -> {

        this.listBox.getSelectedItems().forEach(listItem -> {
            listItem.appendChild(this.secondListBox);
        }); 
     });
}
```

(The code shown is just for testing purposes !)

I want to achieve some expandable list for every Listitem with this approach, but I get this error :

> > Unsupported child for listitem: < Listbox null>

I know that the error already answers my question, but is there another way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should look at Grid - Master Detail? Check the [demo](https://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/grid/master_detail) and the [documentation](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Data/Grid/Detail).

Comment: It could be a solution, but it would be too much work for what I want to achieve. (I'm not lazy, but I want to find a simpler solution)

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you are trying to achieve another option could be to use a [bandbox](https://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/combobox/customizable_combobox)

Comment: Your link helped me finding what I was trying to achieve. [This](https://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/listbox/list_group). Now I'm trying to implement it, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

[`<listitem>` supports `<listcell>` children](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Component%20Reference/Data/Listbox/Listitem#Supported_Children), which then allow [arbitrary child components](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Data/Listbox/Listcell#Supported_Children). So you simply have to create a listcell around the nested listbox.

```
<listbox>
  <listhead>
    <listheader label="outer"/>
  </listhead>
  <listitem>
    <listcell>
      <listbox>
        <listhead>
          <listheader label="nested"/>
        </listhead>
        <listitem label="nested"/>
      </listbox>
    </listcell>
  </listitem>
</listbox>
```

[runnable on zkfiddle](https://zkfiddle.org/sample/1a2j5rl/1-nested-listbox)

or in your case:

```
Listcell cell = new Listcell();
cell.appendChild(this.secondListBox);
listItem.appendChild(cell);
```

however you can't add the same "secondListbox" instance to multiple listcells. You'll just move it around and it will stick to the last listcell parent you append it to.